# Can't get Corresponding node references to work

Tags: nodes

I installed the 'Corresponding node references' module to avoid double editing between nodes that should point to each other (by means of node reference fields). I have followed the instructions to first create nodes with node reference fields and manually editing these fields so that node A point to node B. Then  I checked the box in the modules settings page on admin/config, that indeed showed this correspondance.
But I still have to double edit nodes of these same types. The "other" node is not automatically updated with a reference...
Any suggestions? The site is Drupal 7.42.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It turns out that CNR does not support other languages than English in the stable version. I just installed the dev version and now it works wonderfully. Thanks for maintaining this useful module!